Powerbi Rest API Groups licence information and git integration
I am able to authenticate and create a powerbi Workspace (group) through a python script using an application account (tenant_id, client_id, client_secret).
I would like to perform some HTTP calls to powerbi rest API in order to :

Modify the licence information from PRO to Premium Per User
Connect to git in the git integration section

These operations are possible through powerbi.com using a user account.

Could you confirm whether your requirement is to assign license to groups using REST API?
